# Android clears my application's folder files

Tags: java, android, sd-card

I'm working on an application that downloads many files to the SD card.For a device that doesn't have SD Card. It uses the internal storage.
Whenever the storage goes lower than 500Mb, the operating system clears the folder i'm using to store files these files. Did anybody have a problem like this?.
I think that this problem is related to memory swap for the internal storage(When it gets lower than 500MB, it clears the application folder). 
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: "the operating system clears the folder i'm using to store files these files" -- please explain what folder this is.

Comment: Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/" + my application package name ... Whenever it reaches 500 MB, it deletes all the downloaded files.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be using that mechanism anyway. That probably points to the spot that you get by calling `getExternalFilesDir()` on any `Context` (e.g., an activity), and you *definitely* should be using that method rather than attempting to assemble it yourself. That being said, the behavior you describe feels more like `getExternalCacheDir()`, which is again why you should specifically use `getExternalFilesDir()`. You should also attempt to reproduce this problem in another environment (e.g., an emulator), as what you are seeing might be due to something your device manufacturer added.

Comment: I've already tried getExternalFilesDir() and it hasn't made any change. I tried it on multiple devices and different platforms. This problem is happening only on Samsung(I tried both S4 and Tab8). Do you think that there might be a hack around this?

Comment: Use `getFilesDir()` and put the files on internal storage. From a space standpoint, on the vast majority of Android 3.0+ devices, internal and external storage are on the same partition, so this shift won't affect space usage. The user won't have access to the files, but my guess is that Samsung thinks that since the user can delete the files, they can too. That's inappropriate, but it's also Samsung's call, as it's their device. I will be *very* disappointed if they start randomly wiping out files from `getFilesDir()` under these same conditions.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that `getFilesDir()` also hasn't worked. I tried to create a new folder that the system won't delete(/sd/appname) and it worked. I think that this's not the best choice and i'm not satisfied with leaving the downloaded files in case of removing my application.

Comment: What is the specific `Build.PRODUCT` value of your Galaxy S4? I may see if I can reproduce the error, particularly if I have the same model here in my Secret Mountain Lair. I agree that your workaround is not great, but at this point, I do not have any better suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) can help you out here

> If you'd like to cache some data, rather than store it persistently,
>   you should use getCacheDir() to open a File that represents the
>   internal directory where your application should save temporary cache
>   files.
>
> When the device is low on internal storage space, Android may delete
>   these cache files to recover space. However, you should not rely on
>   the system to clean up these files for you. You should always maintain
>   the cache files yourself and stay within a reasonable limit of space
>   consumed, such as 1MB. When the user uninstalls your application,
>   these files are removed.

The documentation does not say what hard limit is considered while trying to recover space. Whether there is enough space on the internal storage is also not under your control. Repopulate the cache if you find that it is missing and try to maintain a low overhead on the cached files.

As an example I wrote an app a while back that downloads image and sound snippets and caches them. If they are available in the cache I return them. If not I attempt to download them again and put a placeholder image where the actual data is supposed to reside.

Another solution is to store your data in a directory that is not considered a `cache` by the android OS. However you run the risk of overpopulating the user's disk with data and your data will not be removed when the application has been uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

In which directory you are saving your downloaded files?

Please take a look at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html
and
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Also keep in mind the definition of "ExternalStorage":

> "Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer."